# How to fix unresolved reference error in my C program

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I have just learnt about multi-file compilation in C and tried out a test question, but I keep getting the same error while compiling even after following all instructions. My program takes the response of a student to a test in the form of a array (this is done for each student in a separate .c file) and then matches it with the answer key which is declared in the main file. I have defined a function answer() which takes the question number as a parameter and returns the student's response to that question.

The code in each file is as follows

main file (checkanswer.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "answer.h"

int main()
{
    int anskey[4]={5,10,0,4}, score=0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if (anskey[i]==answer(i+1))
        {
            score+=1;
        }
    }
    printf("The score of student is %d",score);
}
```

student1.c

```
#include "answer.h"

int answer(int qno)
{
    int ans[4] = {15,10,2,4};
    return ans[qno-1];
}
```

answer.h

```
int answer(int qno);
```

To do the multi-file compilation, I followed the instructions and generated .o files from both .c files using the -c flag and then used -o to compile and give the executable.

I ran the following in terminal

```
gcc -c checkanswer.c
gcc -c student1.c
gcc -o student1.o checkanswer.o
./a.out
```

And this gives me an error stating "unresolved reference to answer"

Also, I tried using

```
gcc checkanswer.c student1.c
```

Which worked as intended.

So can someone shed some light as to what is wrong with my code and what made the second method work.

Comment: This command is wrong:  `gcc -o student1.o checkanswer.o`  It tells `gcc` to place the executable in `student1.o`.  Change it to `gcc -o myprog student1.o checkanswer.o`  This will produce an executable called `myprog`.  Be sure to recompile `student1` first, since your previous attempts may have destroyed it.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Doesn't gcc by default create an executable named a.out, then why do I have to separately give an executable name

Comment: Because that is what the `-o` option requires… If you want to rely on a default name then just don't provide `-o` at all.

Comment: Because you *told* it to with `-o`.  Do this if you prefer:  `gcc student1.o checkanswer.o`  This will produce the default `a.out` file.  The `-o` options tells it that *the next argument is the name of the output file*.  RTFM.

Comment: Oh ok got it, I'll have to check up on the usages of different flags.
Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: GCC's `-o` stand for "output", it's the output file's name
From the `man gcc`:

> -o file
> Place output in file file. This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

> If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

You should get rid of this error by runninh `gcc -o NAME student1.o checkanswer.o` (you can replace `NAME` by `a.out` or `my_program`)

GCC's `-c` create an object file (.o) that is somewhat a compiled version of your .c file.

Comment: If the default `a.out` is desired, the normal way to do it is omit `-o NAME` entirely.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah, but it was to explain what this flag was doing, and what's best than taking the default value as example to show which value is changed by this flag ? :)